The understanding of sentences
I'd like to ask you if I correctly understand these sentences.
A. He might have bought a bike when we met
B. I knew it might help her when I gave her the pill
C. I knew he might have kicked me when I entered the room
A is ambiguous he either bought a bike before our meeting or during it. It is also possible that he didn't buy anything.
B says that at that time I knew it could be helpful
C I struggle with this example. Does it say that "kicking me" happened before "entering" and because of that that sentence doesn't make sense.

A is a crazy sentence that no real person would say. So is C. Don't you know whether he kicked you?

B is somehow awkward sounding ... maybe I thought it might help her ...

C would make more sense in this format I knew that he might kick me ...

Could you find some real examples, instead?

B is the only idiomatic sentence of the three.
A)  bought expresses an event that happened at a point in time. It is not a synonym for "owned". met expresses an event that happened at a point in time.  He cannot have bought a bike and met you at the same time, unless it was you who sold him the bike and you have a hazy recollection of that transaction.  Change it to "just bought" and it is OK.
C) You cannot know and be in doubt simultaneously about the same thing.
Try to have your sample sentences come from a sane place instead of always testing the boundaries of the absurd.
P.S.  Here is a rewrite of C) that makes sense of it, or tries to:

I knew, when I entered the room, that it might have been him who had kicked me.


Sentences with "might".
Each of the three sentences in OP contain the word "might". 'Might' implies a lower probability or likelihood than'may'.
might have + past participle" is used only in the past and present:
I might have said something bad.
I might have been given this letter but I don't remember.
They might have come already.
Taking each sentence individually: ':

A.He might have bought a bike when we met.
A is ambiguous he either bought a bike before our meeting or during it. It is also possible that he didn't buy anything.

"might have bought" is past tense. I thought he might have bought (before he met me) because last time he told me that he will buy but he didn't as he didn't get the time.
OR.
When we went to the hypermarket, I thought he may buy a bike..

B. I knew it might help her when I gave her the pill.
B says that at that time I knew it could be helpful.

Meaning: I gave her the medicine since I knew it might help her.

C. I knew he might have kicked me when I entered the room.
C.I struggle with this example. Does it say that "kicking me" happened before "entering" and because of that that sentence doesn't make sense.

This sentence is incorrect because it cannot be in the past tense. "have ' should be removed and the the correct modal verb is "will or would". I knew he will kick me, so I kept a safe distance. "Kick" also means "fire someone or remove from employment"

" I thought  she might have eaten when she entered the restaurant". I think it implies that she ate something before and to show that she ate something during the time there I should use "might eat". Am i right?

I think sentence A is all right because there are circumstances where you might not fully remember the details of an event where you were present. If we started dating 20 years ago, you could say "He might have ordered lobster when we went on our second date." It would less sensible (but still grammatically correct) to speak this way about a meeting that you had yesterday.

@Adam might is used for weak possibility - I thought she might have cooked for dinner, so I didn't buy anything. (but I assumed wrongly). If you want to convey strong possibility use "would". I thought she would have cooked.  might is used generally to imply that you thought something but it didn't happen.. In your example above - I thought she might have eaten but she didn't.-.. It doesn't imply that she had eaten for sure.

@James Mathai tell me what is the difference between these two "I thought she might eat when went to the restaurant vs I thought she might have eaten when we went to the restaurant?

First option: I thought she might eat chicken but she ordered lobster "or" I thought she might eat but she didn't eat anything and ordered coffee. The second option doesn't mean anything. It depends what you wish to convey - I thought she might have eaten and would eat only little. But she ordered all the items in the menu.

@HitenStyle You are right. It's a different case if the speaker had forgotten the incident.

@James Mathai Let me present different examples. If you say "I suggested that she should have bought a car", this means that you suggested that she should (already) have bought a car (by the time you spoke). But if you say "I suggested that she should buy a car", then the possibility of buying one was still open to her at the time you spoke to her. Now I'd like to know if these sentences change meaning if we add " when he came to visit" to both of them?

@Adam .First option: I suggested she should have bought a car instead of spending the money on buying a house. (This sentence means she spent/ invested the money somewhere else and you are telling her your opinion).  Second option: This sentence means she has the money or she should save money to buy a car. Please note: Suggested/ thought/ modal Verbs mean that the event didn't happen. There is a possibility of it happening. Like in this case she can either accept or. reject your suggestion.

What can be be very confusing is the usage that we have in Britain (I don't know about anywhere else) where we use 'might have' to criticise someone for not doing something that we think etiquette, decency, kindness, etc, required. When I arrived you might have said 'hello'!

@Adam please note that "might have" is past tense. I have given explanation in my answer. I hope it helps you.
